# Mayavi: imshow issue

Tags: python, mayavi

I am trying to display some data with `mayavi`, first attempt produce inconsistent results when comparing with `matplotlib`. I cannot post images as I don't have reputation 10, the issue is that the images are completely different with the matplotlib one being the correct one.

I've Googled this without much success. I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and mthe Python 2.7 distribution that comes with Ubuntu.

Ipython was executed:

```
ipython --gui=wx --pylab=wx
```

Images generated as:

```
from mayavi  import mlab
mlab.imshow(data)
from matplotlib import pyplot as pylab
pylab.imshow(data)
where data is a 57x122 matrix of float32
```

Comment: `mlab.imshow()` is not guaranteed to produce the same exact same results as `pl.imshow()`. But it should produce something somewhat comparable. Without seeing the images there is no way to debug the problem.